# Comment an element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, comments

I am trying to learn how to use BeautifulSoup. I know how to delete a single element (using `extract` or `decompose`). I was wonder if there's a way to put the element within a comment, so that the element is printed as

```
<!-- <p>HI there</p> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [`Comment`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings) object from the element and use the [`replace_with`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) method to replace the original tag with the comment.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>HI there</p>', 'html.parser')
soup.p.replace_with(Comment(str(soup.p)))
print(soup)
```

> `<!--<p>HI there</p>-->`